# backgroundcolor from navbar stays visible behind dropdown menu when it drops down

Tags: html, css

when i hover over my navbar at some places a menu dropdown, that menu has his own background color. at the bottom of the dropdown menu there is always a part from the navbar background visible, how can i get rid of this? also how can i make the color of the navbar take in the whole size of the screen?

[image: ]Navigation bar[1]]

```css
/*Navigation bar*/
.wrap{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.navbar{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar li{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #101010;
}
.navbar li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.navbar li ul{
   padding-top: 10px;
}
.drop-content li:hover{
    transition-property: background-color;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    background-color: #e60000;
    height: auto;
}
.drop-content li{
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #003566;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 1px hsl(0, 0%, 15%);
}
/* dropdown menu */
.drop-content{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
}
.navbar li:hover .drop-content{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrap">
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li>Link 1
                    <ul class="drop-content">
                        <li>Link 1</li>
                        <li>Link 2</li>
                        <li>Link 3</li>
                        <li>Link 4</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Link 2
                    <ul class="drop-content">
                        <li>Link 1</li>
                        <li>Link 2</li>
                        <li>Link 3</li>
                        <li>Link 4</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Link 3
                    <ul class="drop-content">
                        <li>Link 1</li>
                        <li>Link 2</li>
                        <li>Link 3</li>
                        <li>Link 4</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Link 4</li>
                <li>Link 5</li>
                <li>Link 6</li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

can you also tell me how i can make it little bit more simpler? cause i think i used to many css on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a height of 'navbar' and the background on it, not on li.

```
 .navbar {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #101010;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 45px;
    }
```

Remove the background from li. You're done.

```
.navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: did what you said but then the dropdown creates a scrollbar in the navigation bar. tried it by putting height and color in the wrap and this worked. thx for the help